# Docker Run executing shell command can't access PATH environment variable

Tags: bash, docker, path, sh, docker-run

I'm using [an official image from Microsoft](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-tools) which contains `SQL tools` used to interact with `Microsoft SQL Servers`. If I run the container interactively, I can run `sqlcmd` at the command line without any issue, because it is in the PATH variable:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/var/update/ -w /var/update  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest
root@df20bd19b982:/var/update# sqlcmd
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 13.1.0007.0 Linux
Copyright (c) 2012 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

usage: sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  [-S server or Dsn if -D is provided]
  [-H hostname]          [-E trusted connection]
  [-N Encrypt Connection][-C Trust Server Certificate]
  [-d use database name] [-l login timeout]     [-t query timeout]
  [-h headers]           [-s colseparator]      [-w screen width]
  [-a packetsize]        [-e echo input]        [-I Enable Quoted Identifiers]
  [-c cmdend]
  [-q "cmdline query"]   [-Q "cmdline query" and exit]
  [-m errorlevel]        [-V severitylevel]     [-W remove trailing spaces]
  [-u unicode output]    [-r[0|1] msgs to stderr]
  [-i inputfile]         [-o outputfile]
  [-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
  [-y variable length type display width]
  [-Y fixed length type display width]
  [-p[1] print statistics[colon format]]
  [-R use client regional setting]
  [-K application intent]
  [-M multisubnet failover]
  [-b On error batch abort]
  [-D Dsn flag, indicate -S is Dsn]
  [-X[1] disable commands, startup script, environment variables [and exit]]
  [-x disable variable substitution]
  [-? show syntax summary]

root@b33a916d4230:/var/update# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
root@b33a916d4230:/var/update#
```

> `sqlcmd` is present in `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/` folder which is part of the PATH env. variable.

but If I try to execute the `sqlcmd` command at the `docker run... bash -c 'sqlcmd'`, it won't find it. I echoed PATH environment variable at the same command line and found that its path i.e `/opt/mssql-tools/bin` is already in the PATH.

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/var/update/ -w /var/update  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest bash -c "sqlcmd"
bash: sqlcmd: command not found
```

And to see the `PATH` env. variable, I did the following:

```bash
$docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/var/update/ -w /var/update  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest bash -c 'echo $PATH'

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

**Question 1**: Why Path Variable is different in case we use `bash -c 'commands'`?
**Question 2**: If `bash -c` or `sh -c` creates a new shell, how to execute shell commands with the container's environment variables especially the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run an interactive shell as `root`, it runs the commands from `/root/.bashrc`, which (in this particular image) include

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
```

A better Docker image would have that setting in the `Dockerfile` itself, which exports it to all users of the image.  You can build an image like that yourself easily.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest
ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
```

(Also, the `export` is superfluous; the variable is already exported by the shell.)

If you don't want to mess with the image, try

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/var/update/ -w /var/update \
       mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest \
       bash -c 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/mssql/bin sqlcmd'
```

Comment: This helps me to solve the issue. Defining the PATH is now part of my script and its working correctly now.